# Is there a point to forming bigger squares?

Tags: ios, dots

In *Dots* for iOS, is there a reason to form larger squares, or closed shapes, other than just a the smallest possible (4 dots) square? When you create a simple square of a color, it removes all dots of the same color from the game board, the same as if you strung together many dots and finished by closing a shape off.

Are there point bonuses based on the number of dots in a shape, or some other benefit? Or, is there no point to creating larger shapes other than taking more time to create them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/ultimate-dots-strategy-guide-192446100.html) on Yahoo! Finance (odd place, but there you go) there is no better strategy than using squares of 4, because "squares beget squares", amongst other reasons.

Comment: Completely random site to find that on, but thanks. Sort of figured it out after all this time, but good to have confirmation.